# : EL1008E: Property or field 'LEVEL' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, arraylist, thymeleaf

please assist with the below. I am trying to display an arraylist returned from the controller and display it to an Html table but I get the above error.

here is my controller code:

```
@GetMapping(value="/chart" )
public List<List<CanvasjsChartData.DataPointModel>> chart(Model modelMap) {
    List<List<CanvasjsChartData.DataPointModel>> dataPointsList = canvasjsChartService.getCanvasjsChartData();
    modelMap.addAttribute("dataPointsList", dataPointsList);
    System.out.println("dataPointsList");
    return dataPointsList;
}
```

and this is the table I want to display my list in

```
<table class="table" id="dataTable" style="width:100%">

<thead>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Occurences</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr th:each="item :${dataPointsList}">
   <td th:text="${item.LEVEL}"> </td>
    <td th:text="${item.OCCURENCES}"> </td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I know for sure the ArrayList has the data I require as shown below I dont know why its giving me the error
[image: arralist]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debug shows you have an `List<List<CanvasjsChartData.DataPointModel>>` (two Lists inside of each other) -- when your HTML is expecting `List<CanvasjsChartData.DataPointModel>`.  You should fix that in your controller/model by only returning a single list.

You could also display your HTML like this (where you loop over the 0th element of the outer array):

```
<tr th:each="item :${dataPointsList[0]}">
  <td th:text="${item.LEVEL}" />
  <td th:text="${item.OCCURENCES}" />
</tr>
```